# Date of Editing Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date

Is it possible in SharePoint to make it so that when editing a column in another column, the date of editing appears? Preferably by means of the SharePoint itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a SharePoint default column named **Modified** - this shows the date of last edit/update to list item.

[image]

Follow this Microsoft official documentation to show Modified column in list or library view: [Show or hide a column in a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-columns-in-a-list-or-library-b820db0d-9e3e-4ff9-8b8b-0b2dbefa87e2)

---

**Update from comments**:

You can create a calculated column in your list based on Modified column to show the date in specific format. Use formula for calculated column like:

```
=TEXT([Modified],"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

**Output**:

[image]

---

Or try changing display format for Modified column from list settings > column settings like:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this option is an exception. Because i need a date in the format dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: Check updated answer, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Not really, if you describe the problem in full, then; I need that after changing a column in another column, the answer date automatically appears. Can you tell me what code to write to me, I'm quite new at this. So far my code looks like this. "=IF( [Answer]="Compliant"; "dd.mm.yyyy";"

Comment: Do you want to capture the date when question was answered (answer field updated in form)? For this requirements, you cannot use calculated column. You will need to customize list form using Power apps and capture the current/today's date when answer field is updated.

Comment: Yes, you understood everything correctly, it is a sad that it will not work. Can you answer one more question? Is it possible with the help of Calculated Columns to make it so that after filling in one column, the name of the person who did it appears in another? But not in the format "Who changed it" but in the one I need, with the ID of my company?

Comment: No, not possible using calculated column.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this? I'll be very grateful

Comment: You maybe able to do it using Power apps. You can fetch user profile details using Office365Users connector in power apps.